# Spring MVC - inject context-param from web.xml

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web.xml, spring-annotations

I have defined the context params in web.xml

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>apikey</param-name>
        <param-value>45370652</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>secretkey</param-name>
        <param-value>3eada72ef0ae12e15b138ae098c268c087f08ca8</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

I have enabled `@Component` and `@Value` annotations in Class and field levels in the bean class. But, it doesn't seem to read them. It is always null

@Component
public class TokBoxSettings {

```
@Value("${apikey}")
private  String apikey; 

@Value("${secretkey}")
private  String secretkey;
```

I have also added the below bean mapping to `spring-servlet.xml` for configuring PropertyPlaceholder

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
</bean>
```

Please let me know what i have missed

Comment: Generally bean definition and settings are contained in `@Configuration` annotated classes. Did you try changing `@Component` to `@Configuration` for `TokBoxSettings`? Those two stereotypes may differ in ordering.

Answer (score 1):

I am junior spring + hibernate developer,I have one alternative solution for this question,may be you know

I used bean name and its property to set direct context-param value

```
<bean ...>
   <property name="apikey" value="${apikey}" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set property ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders to true inside bean declaration. i.e. add below tags in `spring-servlet.xml`

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Its worked for me.